# "Which" vs "in which"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

What are 'in' in these sentences for?

*1. Our algebra class is a heterogeneous one **in which** bright students are juxtaposed with slower ones.*

*2. Eulogy is a speech or piece of writing **in which** you praise someone or something*

Can I rewrite them in these forms?

*1. Our algebra class is a heterogeneous one  **which / that**  bright students are juxtaposed with slower ones.*

2.Eulogy is a speech or piece of writing  **which /that** you praise someone or something

How does rewriting affect the meaning?

Comment: This is the account *into which* the money should be deposited. This is the account *from which* the money should be withdrawn. June 25 is the day *on which* these banking transactions should occur. This is the power-of-attorney *by which* you are authorized to make the transactions. Money-laundering is the purpose *for which* these transactions are being made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *in* is obligatory: it defines the syntactic role of the relativizer.

The "canonical" sentences which underlie these relative clauses look like this:

> You praise someone or something **in** a eulogy.
>   Bright students are juxtaposed with slower ones **in** our class.

These sentences would be meaningless without the *in*s—

> <sup>∗</sup> You praise someone or something a eulogy.
>   <sup>∗</sup> Bright students are juxtaposed with slower ones our class.

We have no idea here what *a eulogy* and *our class* were doing there. Exactly the same thing is true if you omit the *in*s governing *which* or *that*, which "stand for" *a eulogy* and *our class* — we don't know why the *which*es are there.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  <sub>*marks an utterance as ungrammatical*</sub>